# What is the difference between "einführen" and "gründen"?

Tags: difference

I looked it up but couldn't come up with some explanation that I felt comfortable with.

Comment: Hey and welcome. As these two words have little in common you should provide an example to clear up your question. Or as said in the tour: Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do. :)

Comment: Actually the meaning of these words is so different, I can't imagine a scenario where they come even close.

Comment: @guidot  Yes, you can: "*Wir wollen ein neues Unternehmen am Markt einführen.*" vs "*Wir wollen ein neues Unternehmen gründen.*" Both sentences say more or less the same. But I admit this is a very specific situation.

Answer (score 4):

"Einführen" means introducing something **into** a context, where it wasn't present or known before. Either physically (putting a key into a lock) or as concept (introducing an idea into a discussion).

"Gründen" means creating/**founding** something that did not exist before. Either physically (building) or as a concept (company).

The words also give you a significant hint on the inherent meaning:
"Einführen" consists of the words "Ein" (into) and "führen" (lead). Which is why i used Intro-Duce (~lead into) as a translation.

"Gründen" is the verbalized form of the noun "Grund" (~foundation or ~reason).

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "Ich gründe ein Haus." Can you specify an example sentence? Might this be a regional use?

Comment: @infinitezero: You are right, what i tried to hint at is very close to creating a concept: "eine Stadt gründen", "eine Familie gründen", "einen Hausstand gründen", "eine Existenz gründen". However, "Gründung" is actually a stage of construction, so maybe there is a verb for the process as well: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCndung_(Bauwesen)